# Is it possible to have multiple domain handled by one laravel app?

Tags: laravel, routes

Lets say i have domain1.com and domain2.com. I want both of them to point to the same laravel app but shows different page. For example, domain1.com would reference controller X that would render page X while domain2.com would reference controller Y that would render page Y. Is that possible? If so how would i code the routing? Please keep in mind that i'm not talking about subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You could make multiple web route files.

Then in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` in the `mapWebRoutes()` method switch between route files based on the hostname.

```php
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        $request = $this->app->make(Request::class);

        if ($request->getHost() === "example.com") {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/example.com.web.php'));
        } else {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/othersite.com.web.php'));
        }
    }
```

If you need to split your controllers into separate namespaces (to avoid mixing them up) you can also manage that in that method by specifying the namespaces.

Update:

An example on how to use an if in the routes file, as requested in the comments:

```php
//routes/web.php

if (request()->getHost() === "example.com") {
    Route::get('/', 'OneController@index');
} else {
    Route::get('/', 'AnotherController@index');
}
```

Comment: For my case, the various domain that would point to the same laravel app would only reference the same 1 or 2 controllers. Those controllers would then generate the views dynamically based on the domain, so i think for my case it would be a bit overkill to have every domain have its own web file. At least in my opinion. Maybe you have a different opinion on that? If i were to only use 1 web file, how would i do it? Also, how would i handle routing with dynamic domain? For example, if a user already have a domain that they would like to use.

Comment: @FirdausIndradhirmaya You could have some if conditions in your routes file the same way if your requirement is less that that. But if it's just one or two controllers, why not base the decision on what view to show in said controller methods instead.

Comment: Can you please clarify how to have a condition in route file based on host?

```$request = $this->app->make(Request::class);

if ($request->getHost() === "example.com") {
    Route::post('/', 'example_controller@example_method');
}
```

Like this you mean?

Comment: thanks! Really big help, though i can't test it now because im not there yet on my project. I will accept your answer once i get to that part of my project sometimes next week.